# How can i convert linux text file to windows text file by using qt?

Tags: c++, qt

When I copy text files to USB flash memory with Qt on raspberry pi 3 , and when I open these text files on Windows , text file `'\n'` characters not seem to work on Windows.

I searched this topic and I saw that text file formats are different on Linux and Windows.So I have to copy Linux based text files to Flash Memory with Qt and open these files on Windows.

Comment: How about `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few characters which can indicate a new line. The usual ones are these two:

```
'\n' or '0x0A' (10 in decimal) -> This character is called "Line Feed" (LF).
'\r' or '0x0D' (13 in decimal) -> This one is called "Carriage return" (CR).
```

Different Operating Systems handle newlines in a different way. Here is a short list of the most common ones:

**DOS and Windows :**

They expect a newline to be the combination of two characters, namely `'\r\n'` (or 13 followed by 10).

**Unix (and hence Linux as well) :**

Unix uses a single `'\n'` to indicate a new line.

**Mac :**

Macs use a single `'\r'`.

**EDIT :** As MSalters mentioned Mac OSX is Unix and uses `\n`. The single `\r` is ancient Mac OS9

Comment: Mac OSX is Unix and uses `\n`. The single `\r` is ancient Mac OS9.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are just transporting the file, not doing anything with it, but I can't think of another option than opening it and rewrite the line endings.

If you open the .txt file on Windows and read from it (with c++ or c++/Qt) and then write the lines as you get them to a new file, the line endings should then fit the Windows sepcifics.

You can read the file like this:

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(filePath);    

std::ofstream file2;
file2.open(filePath2); 

while(std::getline(file, line)) 
{
   file2<<line;
}
```

[std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)

At least the documentation states that getline searches for '\n', it should work on windows and Unix. If it doesn't, you can still set the delimeter to '\n'.

If you want to write the file 'Windowslike' on your raspberry, you can try to replace the '\n' characters with '\r\n'

It should look somehow like this:

```
std::string myFileAsString;
std::string toReplace = "\n";
std::string replaceWith = "\r\n";
myFileAsString.replace(myFileAsString.find(toReplace), toReplace.length(), replaceWith);
```

where find searches for '\n' and then replaces it with '\r\n'

[replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/)
[find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)